# Wordpress Query Loop Block URL parameter filtering

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, wordpress-gutenberg, gutenberg-blocks

I need to find some way to allow front-end filtering of the results of a query loop block. The ideal way to do this would be to use URL parameters to modify the query loop results, similar to the search block.

Is there an easy way to do this with a variation on the Query Loop block? Or am I going to have to make something entirely custom for this purpose? I'd love to use as much out-of-the-box code as possible.

Answer (score 0):

You can [extend the Query Loop](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/how-to-guides/block-tutorial/extending-the-query-loop-block/) block by creating a variation that specifies query parameters. Below is a simple block variation for the setting search parameter of the Query Loop:

**JS**

```js
registerBlockVariation( 'core/query', {
    name: 'my-plugin/list-keyword',
    icon: 'smiley',
    attributes: {
        query: {
            search: 'keyword', // equivalent to /s?=keyword
            /* and optionally any other query settings.. */
        },
    },
    ...
} );
```

You can then add your Query block variation to any post/page/template.

For the front-end, if you are editing the Search template for your theme, I would use the Button block to provide links for changing the search parameters, no block variation required, eg:

**Site Editor > Templates > Search**
[image: Search template with buttons]

Depending on your end goal, the documentation on [Extending the Query](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/how-to-guides/block-tutorial/extending-the-query-loop-block/#extending-the-query) may be useful as well.

Comment: `query: { search: 'keyword',  }, },`

this part does not work. You may pass here any params, but query block variation always output the same params:
`"query":{"perPage":3,"pages":0,"offset":0,"postType":"post","order":"desc","orderBy":"date","author":"","search":"","exclude":[],"sticky":"","inherit":false}`

You can change search to anything in your code, but it always "". You can pass any new param in your code - but output amount of params always the same.

Comment: @IvanFrolov My example covers the just changing the search parameter & assumes the rest of the required values are added as needed. Unless you define your variation by name, the query defaults you describe will be used, see [Making Gutenberg recognise your variation](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/how-to-guides/block-tutorial/extending-the-query-loop-block/#making-gutenberg-recognize-your-variation)

Comment: @SWalsh sure I got it. And I just want to clarify that your `search: 'keyword'` does not work. I tested it, query anyway output default `"search":""`

Answer (score -1):

This was addressed on wordpress.stackexchange.com:

> To avoid modifying the main query, you might consider adding a custom query variable with PHP, and use `?qls=foo` instead of `?s=foo`.
>
> To target the corresponding query loop, add the text :query-loop-search into the search box of the query loop block in the editor.
>
> Then we could grab the value of the custom query variable `?qls=foo` and set it as the search variable for the target query with a little more PHP.

Source:
https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/407888/how-to-filter-query-loop-block-with-a-search-string-from-the-query-parameters